# Angular 12 app still being cached with output-hashing=all

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 12 application that has different build environments (dev/staging/prod) and I have configured these with output hashing on in `angular.json`:

```
"configurations": {
    "production": {
        "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ],
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all" <-----
```

The output files do include a hash, but I am still seeing the old version unless I do a hard refresh in the browser.

```
main.07258fce7f84f8b6013e.js
polyfills.4cc5b416b55531e38cd8.js
runtime.734c276f75a5d81bc54b.js
```

The landing page is just a login form but the version is shown beneath the form.  It shows the old version until the hard-refresh in the browser, at which point it correctly shows the new version.

Is this due to `index.html` being cached along with all of it's old JS references?

If so how do I cache bust this?

Comment: never heard of this problem before, what you've done should not require a hard refresh - is "outputHashing": "all" defined for all environments? in  the code you've given its only defined for prod env

Comment: @danday74 Yes it is for all environments, and even with this production set up, when built as `--configuration production` and deployed, it is still requiring a hard refresh.  My only guess was it is caching `index.html` which references the old scripts and can't be hashed.  If those are also cached will it simply load the old site as it was?

Comment: Hi, are you using a service-worker? (`@angular/pwa` or something similar)

Comment: How can I add the output-hashing to my default config? so that it is not only being hashed on production

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by instructing the web server cache control policy to not cache the HTML file.  This is necessary because the HTML file contains the references to the Angular hashed scripts and CSS.

We are pushing out frequent updates so for now, I am setting this to to agressively *not* cache, but it can be adjusted to longer time periods as needed.

In our case we are using IIS, and I had to create an IIS rewrite rule in the web.config file.

```
<outboundRules>
    <rule name="RewriteCacheControlForHTMLFiles" preCondition="FileEndsWithHtml">
        <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Cache_Control" pattern=".*" />
        <action type="Rewrite" value="max-age=0" />
    </rule>
    <preConditions>
        <preCondition name="FileEndsWithHtml">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="\.html$" />
        </preCondition>
    </preConditions>
</outboundRules>
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you're using a service worker (eg `@angular/pwa` which installs `@angular/service-worker` along), you're entire angular app is being cached by the browser. This includes `index.html` + all javascript files + all stylesheets.

To have a new version of your application pushed to your users, you have to do 2 things:

Update your `ngsw-config.json` on each new release:

```
{
    "version": 1, // Or ascending
    ...
}
```

Call `SwUpdate`:

```
constructor(private swUpdate: SwUpdate) {
    ...

    //#region Check for updates
    if (this.swUpdate.isEnabled) {
      this.swUpdate.activated.subscribe((upd) => {
        window.location.reload();
      });
      this.swUpdate.available.subscribe((upd) => {
        this.swUpdate.activateUpdate();
      }, (error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
      this.swUpdate.checkForUpdate().then(() => {
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.error('Could not check for app updates', error);
      });
    }
    //#endregion
}
```

[Here's an example](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MP.Web/ClientApp/src/app/app.component.ts#L87)